# Not compatible JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a web site I have included a custom Google Map and a custom slideshow.

This is the HTML file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>Polideportivo Los Cedros</title>
            <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function initialize() {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.427917, -3.657941);
                    var settings = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                        navigationControl: true,
                        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
                    var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(40.427288, -3.657919);
                    var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: companyPos,
                        map: map,
                        title:"Some title"
                    })
                ;}
            </script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body onload="initialize()">
            <div id="background">
                <div id="Base"><img src="images/Base.png"></div>
                <div id="graficotiempo"><!-- www.TuTiempo.net - Ancho:324px - Alto:70px -->
                <div id="TT_RCZkE1E1kSQDnshK7fzzzDDzDKUKTKrlLd1YEsy5Kkz"><a href="http://www.tutiempo.net/Tiempo-Madrid-E28001.html">El Tiempo en Madrid</a></div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tutiempo.net/widget/eltiempo_RCZkE1E1kSQDnshK7fzzzDDzDKUKTKrlLd1YEsy5Kkz"></script>
            </div>
            <div id="googlePlano">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:195px; height:132px"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="Capaslide">
                <div id="flip" class="cycle-slideshow" 
                    data-cycle-fx='flipVert' 
                    data-cycle-auto-height="4:3"
                    data-cycle-delay="400"
                    data-cycle-timeout="4000" >

                    <img src="slide_inicial/silde1.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
                    <img src="slide_inicial/silde2.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
                    <img src="slide_inicial/silde3.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
                    <img src="slide_inicial/silde4.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>

                    <img src="slide_inicial/silde5.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
                    <img src="slide_inicial/silde6.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
                    <img src="slide_inicial/silde7.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
                    <img src="slide_inicial/silde8.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
                    <img src="slide_inicial/silde9.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mail"><a href="mailto:info@polideportivoloscedros.es"><img src="images/mail.png" ></a></div>
            <div id="tw"><img src="images/tw.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/twitter_realce.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='images/tw.png'"></div>
            <div id="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/facebook_realce.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/facebook.png'"></div>
            <div id="logohome"><img src="images/logohome.png"></div>
            <div id="logoclubsuperior"><a href="club.html"><img src="images/logoclubsuperior.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/6.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logoclubsuperior.png'"></a></div>
            <div id="logopiscinasuperior"><img src="images/logopiscinasuperior.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/5.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logopiscinasuperior.png'"></div>
            <div id="logotenissuperior"><img src="images/logotenissuperior.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/4.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logotenissuperior.png'"></div>
            <div id="logopadelsuperior"><img src="images/logopadelsuperior.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/3.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logopadelsuperior.png'"></div>
            <div id="logofitnesssuperior"><img src="images/logofitnesssuperior.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logofitnesssuperior.png'"></div>
            <div id="logootrossuperior"><img src="images/logootrossuperior.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logootrossuperior.png'"></div>
        </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

The problem is that the included custom Google Map should be selectable, that means that the user should be able to click on the map and move it and zoom in and zoom out on it. After including the slide show, the map is not selectable any more.

These are the lines that show the slide show:

```
<div id="flip" class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx='flipVert' 
    data-cycle-auto-height="4:3"
    data-cycle-delay="400"
    data-cycle-timeout="4000"
    >
    <img src="slide_inicial/silde1.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
    <img src="slide_inicial/silde2.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
    <img src="slide_inicial/silde3.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
    <img src="slide_inicial/silde4.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>

    <img src="slide_inicial/silde5.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
    <img src="slide_inicial/silde6.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
    <img src="slide_inicial/silde7.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
    <img src="slide_inicial/silde8.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
    <img src="slide_inicial/silde9.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
</div>
```

The slide show works fine, but after inserting the previous lines, the map is shown but not selectable. If I remove the previous lines, then the map is selectable again.

I am not able to detect the source of the issue.

Comment: You should always have quotes around your HTML attribute values. In other words, after `=`. Also, you cannot expect `this` to work the way you want, without being inside of a function that is assigned to your Event. It's a best practice to separate your JavaScript from your HTML altogether. Use external JavaScript.

Comment: @PHPglue, thank you for your advices, but after including the needed quotes, the issue is not solved.

Comment: @mvasco - You have an embeded script in your widget subdirectory with a name that starts with eltiempo_RCZ.... What's the purpose of that script?

Comment: @maurice, it is a script to include a weather report widget. I have check the site with and without this widget and the issue is the same. Thank you.

Comment: @mvasco - In that case, your code works, except that there is no "flipVert" effects in that slider (it will revert to fade), and your img tags should be self enclosed, e.g., use slash greater than sign

Comment: @maurice, I don't really understand what you mean. Would you mind to explain it to me with other words?

Comment: @mvasco - When you specify data-cycle-fx='flipVert' with the slider, the slider will ignore it because it does not know that value. Instead it will use 'fade' as the effect... Your images tag should technically be using the form <img blahblahblah/>   instead of <img blablahblah>... I tried your sample by reducing to the minimum (removed stuff like your stylesheet, substituded my own images, changes as described by the start of this comment) and it all worked. I'm able to use the google map controls while the slider was doing its thing. I used firefox as the browser on my desktop.

Comment: @maurice, would you mind putting your comment as answer to my question including a line example from the slider as you suggest. I am using Safari and Chrome as browser, and I can't use the map controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By request, here's the reduced code that worked with firefox on my desktop (edited from cut-paste error):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>XZZZZZZZXXXXXXZZZZZZZZ</title>
  <!-- <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.427917, -3.657941);
    var settings = {
     zoom: 15,
     center: latlng,
     mapTypeControl: true,
     mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
     navigationControl: true,
     navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
    var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(40.427288, -3.657919);
    var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: companyPos,
      map: map,
      title:"Some title"
    });
   }
  </script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

  <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>

 </head>

 <body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="background">
   <div id="Base"><img src="images/Base.png"></div>
   <div id="graficotiempo"><!-- www.TuTiempo.net - Ancho:324px - Alto:70px -->
    <div id="TT_RCZkE1E1kSQDnshK7fzzzDDzDKUKTKrlLd1YEsy5Kkz">
     <!-- <a href="http://www.tutiempo.net/Tiempo-Madrid-E28001.html">El Tiempo en Madrid</a> -->
    </div>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://www.tutiempo.net/widget/eltiempo_RCZkE1E1kSQDnshK7fzzzDDzDKUKTKrlLd1YEsy5Kkz"> </script> -->
    </div>
    <div id="googlePlano">
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width:195px; height:132px">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="Capaslide">
    <div id=flip class="cycle-slideshow"
         data-cycle-fx='fade'
         data-cycle-auto-height="4:3"
         data-cycle-delay="400"
         data-cycle-timeout="4000">
     <img src="slide_inicial/silde1.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=fade />
     <img src="slide_inicial/silde2.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=fade />
     <img src="slide_inicial/silde3.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=fade />
     <img src="slide_inicial/silde4.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=fade />
     <img src="slide_inicial/silde5.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=fade />
     <img src="slide_inicial/silde6.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=fade />
     <img src="slide_inicial/silde7.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=fade />
     <img src="slide_inicial/silde8.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=fade />
     <img src="slide_inicial/silde9.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=fade />
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="mail">
    <a href="mailto:info@polideportivoloscedros.es">
     <img src="images/mail.png" />
    </a>
   </div>
   <div id="tw">
    <img src="images/tw.png"
         onmouseover="this.src='images/twitter_realce.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/tw.png'" />
   </div>
   <div id="facebook">
    <img src="images/facebook.png"
         onmouseover="this.src='images/facebook_realce.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/facebook.png'" />
   </div>
   <div id="logohome"><img src="images/logohome.png" /></div>
   <div id="logoclubsuperior">
    <a href="club.html">
     <img src="images/logoclubsuperior.png"
          onmouseover="this.src='images/6.png'"
          onmouseout="this.src='images/logoclubsuperior.png'" />
    </a>
   </div>
   <div id="logopiscinasuperior">
    <img src="images/logopiscinasuperior.png"
         onmouseover="this.src='images/5.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/logopiscinasuperior.png'">
   </div>
   <div id="logotenissuperior">
    <img src="images/logotenissuperior.png"
         onmouseover="this.src='images/4.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/logotenissuperior.png'" />
   </div>
   <div id="logopadelsuperior">
    <img src="images/logopadelsuperior.png"
         onmouseover="this.src='images/3.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/logopadelsuperior.png'" />
   </div>
   <div id="logofitnesssuperior">
    <img src="images/logofitnesssuperior.png"
         onmouseover="this.src='images/2.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/logofitnesssuperior.png'" />
   </div>
   <div id="logootrossuperior">
    <img src="images/logootrossuperior.png"
         onmouseover="this.src='images/1.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/logootrossuperior.png'" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your solution, the weather report widget is not shown. And the map controls are enabled...right?

Comment: Yes, that weather widget is not there.  Map mouse controls zoom+/- pan work.

Comment: Then the problems lies on the weather widget or on the style sheet. In your solution, you have removed the link to the style sheet. Now I have tested it activating the style sheet and without weather widget, and the map controls are disabled. That should mean that the problem lies in the style sheet, right?

Comment: Could be, but I didn't download the CSS files so that I can reduce the number of factors that could go wrong.

Comment: The problem must at another place. May be a wrong <div>. But your solution is working removing the weather widget. I will accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you missed " " in  at the start of your code. in the lower area
try this :

```
<div id="flip" class="cycle-slideshow" 
data-cycle-fx='flipVert' 
data-cycle-auto-height="4:3"
data-cycle-delay="400"
data-cycle-timeout="4000"
>
<img src="slide_inicial/silde1.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
<img src="slide_inicial/silde2.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
<img src="slide_inicial/silde3.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
<img src="slide_inicial/silde4.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>

<img src="slide_inicial/silde5.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
<img src="slide_inicial/silde6.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
<img src="slide_inicial/silde7.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
<img src="slide_inicial/silde8.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
<img src="slide_inicial/silde9.jpg" class=first data-cycle-fx=flipVert>
</div>
```

Comment: An explanation of how you expect your solution to resolve issue would help. Also an explanation of changes made so that people don't have to be human diff tools. `Try this` isn't much of an answer

Comment: Still missing quotes, and not the solution.

Comment: no quotes on single word attribute values is also valid html.